# Laravel Nova, only show active records from menu on create resource page

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

In Laravel (Nova) I got two resources Motor and Brand.

Right now I select a Brand from a menu (BelongsTo), when creating a new Motor. This works great.

```
Nova > Motor

BelongsTo::make('Select a Brand', 'brand', 'App\Nova\Brand'),
```

How can I make it, so only active Brands are listed in the menu?

I have tried to add this to my Brand model:

```
class Brand extends Model
{
    public static function relatableMotors(NovaRequest $request, $query)
    {
        return $query->where('active', 1);
    }
}
```

No errors, but still showing both active and inactive Brands in my related menu when creating a new Motor.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution i think.

Added this to Nova > Resource.php:

```
public static function relatableBrands(NovaRequest $request, $query)
    {
        return $query->where('active', 1);
    }
```